# Choosing the right version of GCP''s Datastore library for .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

For GCP's Datastore I see two versions of Nuget, not sure what are the difference between,  and which one to use when working with .Net Core applications

```
Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1
Google.Apis.Datastore.v1beta3
```

The second one does appears to be recently updated though while the sample application at https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-csharp using the first one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer/authority: I'm the primary author of `Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1`, and I'm responsible for the Google Cloud Client Libraries for .NET. So I know what I'm talking about here, but I do have biases :)

You should really be picking between `Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1` and `Google.Apis.Datastore.v1` - there's no point in using a beta library at this point.

However, `Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1` is the preferred library. The differences are:

- `Google.Apis.Datastore.v1` works over HTTP/1.1 with JSON payloads. `Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1` uses gRPC and protocol buffer payloads.
- `Google.Apis.Datastore.v1` is entirely autogenerated, with our "old" code generation technology. It should work, but it's not as clean as the more recent code generation. `Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1` is a mixture of generated code and hand-written code.

The part about the hand-written code is important - that's how we have classes like [`DatastoreTransaction`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1.DatastoreTransaction.html) which is more pleasant to work with than manually keeping track of the transaction ID etc. There are also a lot of conversions and extra methods on protobuf messages to make Datastore easier to work with.

Both libraries should work fine with .NET Core, but `Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1` does require a gRPC native library, which currently only works with x86 and x64. Neither library is supported on UWP, Xamarin or Unity at the moment, but there may be *some* contexts where `Google.Apis.Datastore.v1` works for you but the gRPC library doesn't. I would start off by trying to use `Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1` though.

Comment: I guess I need to convert the library which is LINQ over Datastore https://github.com/neil-119/GAE-NET to use gRPC instead, do you guys have any plans to support natively with LINQ

Comment: And can you point me in the right direction for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50589928/how-to-differentiate-whether-the-code-is-running-in-an-emulator-or-in-gke-when-w

Comment: @skjagini: No, we have no plans for a LINQ provider for Datastore at the moment. Never say never, but there are no plans at the moment.